# Router or adapter MAC address visible with javascript?

Tags: router, javascript, mac-address, adapter

I would like to know when a site uses javascript is the MAC address of the specific router being used or that of the computer's adapter visible, which one?

Comment: Javascript shouldn't have access to the MAC address

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have access to MAC addresses, period. The server itself would only be able to see your MAC address if it was on the same LAN, which it won't be if it's a site on the internet and your computer/router is not directly on the internet. (If you have an ISP, that probably means there's an ISP network between you and the site.)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. A MAC address is purely used for computers on the same network to communicate at a simple level.

This information is not used by applications using the Internet (in general - computers are addressed by IP address, not MAC address.)

It is entirely practical - and not uncommon for Internet connected computers to not have any MAC  (eg dial up modems, Cellular Internet connections, point to point connections, ATM / frame relay connections, serial connections), and similarly it's common for a computer to have more then 1 MAC address where there is more then 1 network, WIFI or Bluetooth interface.